# python 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getroottree'

Tags: python, xml, soap-client

I'm setting up a client for a SOAP webservice. I am using zeep to send my `xml` file, however, it is displaying the following error:

> ```
> elementtree = rootelement.getroottree()  
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getroottree'
> ```

Below is my code, which traverses a folder in search of XML files and soon after an example of an `xml` file

**My code:**

```
from zeep import Client
from xml.dom import minidom
import os
import glob

hash = "9f56ccba6d88d2b089ab8a9fb40dd46f"
diretorioIn =  'M:\\TRACKING\\ENVIO2\\'
diretorioOut = 'M:\\TRACKING\\'
count = 0

while(count < 1):

    for file in glob.glob(diretorioIn +'*.XML'):

        arquivo = minidom.parse(file)
        arquivo = arquivo.toxml()

        client = Client('https://localizacoes.php?wsdl')
        result = client.service.AdicionarLocalizacoes(arquivo, hash)


        print(result.AdicionarLocalizacoesReport._value_1)
```

**My xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<localizacoes>
<localizacao carga_id="" placa_veiculo="BAP9999" cpf_motorista="" placa_implemento="BAP6666" ocorrencia_id="00" latitude="-23,2499" longitude="-47,9885" localizacao_descricao="SP-QUADRA-Rodovia Presidente Castello Branco" localizacao_data="05/04/2017 10:30:39" entrega=""/>
</localizacoes>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when you have a file in there that contains only white space.

The same error occurs here, and the bug reported suggests that white space may be the problem: https://github.com/collective/collective.liches/issues/1.
It uses different code, but maybe the cause is the same.